# How to debug why `notify-send` fails?

Tags: bash, notifications, cinnamon

After a fresh restart, the `notify-send` command on Cinnamon desktop successfully shows a couple of notifications. But afterwards (within the first 5 minutes, and after 3 notifications have been executed) they don't appear anymore; neither on the desktop nor in the history of notifications in the panel applet.

The command itself outputs nothing, and the `man` page doesn't mention anything about an error log. Is there some simple anti-spam limit maybe per-application? How do I find out why this happens?